# How do I check whether the next number is going to be negative or not?

Tags: java

I'm having a little trouble completing an assignment for my class.
The instructions are:

> Read from all 12 monthly files and print the starting balance for each
>   month. If the balance is ever negative, print a warning message to standard output.

An example of what the format of all the files look like is:

```
dep 350.18
wdr 500
wdr 4.99
wdr 7.95
wdr 25
dep 50
wdr 199.99
wdr 25
wdr 25
wdr 9.72
```

My code so far is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Excercise4 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
    String filename = sc.next();
    File myFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
    float temp = 0;
    float sum = 0;
     while(myScanner.hasNextFloat()) {
          temp = myScanner.nextFloat(); 
          sum += temp;
          System.out.println(sum);
     }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if I need to make edits to the question.

Comment: Where did you write the negative balance checking code? Write it first, make some mistakes and we will help you to overcome your problem.

Comment: Tip: You might want to use `filename = sc.nextLine();`

Comment: You'll want to use `if` statements and `String.equals()` to determine whether or not the input line is a deposit or a withdrawal. If it's a deposit, you add it with `sum += ` as you are, if it's a withdrawal, you would subtract it from sum with `sum -= `.

Answer (score 1):

1. The file contains both a transaction type (dep, wdr) and an amount. You need to deposit (dep) or withdraw (wdr) the amount depending on the type.
2. You are printing the balance after each transaction. You should only be printing after each file.
3. You should check after each transaction whether the balance is negative and print a warning.
4. You need to loop through a number of files - currently you only read one.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check whether the next number is going to be negative or not?

Let's call `sum` the `balance` instead.

```
double balance = 0;
String line;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    line = myScanner.nextLine();  // Read the line
    String[] parts = line.split("\\s+"); // split on one or more whitespaces
    String action = parts[0]; // 'dep' or 'wdr'
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
    if ("wdr".equals(action) && amount > balance) {
        // Warning: not enough funds
        break; // exit the loop, if required
    }
    balance += amount;
}

System.out.println(balance); // Print the final balance
```

Comment: I think OP means if the total amount appears to be negative. That is, if it's a withdrawal, `if (sum - temp < 0){ //warning }`

Comment: Oh, I guess that makes sense. Didn't really think about `wdr` vs. `dep`. Still not clear what identifies the beginning of a month, though

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm getting an array index out of bounds error on 'parseDouble(parts[1])', any thoughts on why?

Comment: Obviously the line that you've read does not have 2 elements separated by a space

Comment: apparently it's a tab in between the string and the numbers

Comment: You can change the `" "` to `"\\s+"`